Re-publish message to the same queue in MassTransit
I use masstransit 8 + amazon sqs/sns, the app is running in Windows Docker container.
My consumer is processing message by scheduled time it can be up to few hours. Due to sqs limitation max delay until the message remains invisible to consumers is 15 minutes, so message could get to queue earlier than scheduled time and in order to wait required time I re-publish this message to the same queue.
My questions are:

Could such approach leads to duplicate messages in queue ?
Is it bad practice or not to re-publish same message to same queue ?
Are there any other side effects that I could expect using this approach ?

The code sample as below:
internal class TestConsumer : IConsumer<TestEvent>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestEvent> context)
    {
        var message = context.Message;

        // due to sqs limitation message could be automatically consumed earlier than scheduled polling time.
        // in this case we re-publish the same message and wait until the scheduled time.
        if (DateTime.UtcNow < message.ScheduledTime)
        {
            var uri = context.ReceiveContext.InputAddress;

            await context.ScheduleSend(uri, message.ScheduledTime, message).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return;
        }

        // process business logic here
    }
}

public class TestEvent
{
    public DateTime ScheduledTime { get; set; }
}


SQS max is 12 hours, not 15 minutes.

hi Chris, yep, I mean sqs delay period for message until it remains invisible to consumers. I've edited the question, could you please have a look ?
